# Why is sessionFactory not injected for unit test using Grails 3.2?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, spock

I'm running into an issue where a unit test that extends HibernateSpec is failing due to the `sessionFactory` not being injected into the service under test. Whenever a method on the `sessionFactory` is called during the test, I get a `NullPointerException` (e.g. `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getClassMetadata() on null object`) and the test subsequently fails.

I'm using Grails 3.2.4 and Hibernate 5.

This was working when the test used `@TestMixin(HibernateTestMixin)`, but it looks like with some updates, the mixin is deprecated and suggests using `HibernateSpec` instead.

Here's a snippet from my test:

```
class TestDatabaseServiceSpec extends HibernateSpec {
    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test method"() {
        when: 
        service.method() 

        then:
        true
    }
}
```

And here is a snippet from the service under test:

```
void method() {
...
  TABLE_NAMES.add(sessionFactory.getClassMetadata('MyDomain').tableName)
...
}
```

I have tried to set `service.sessionFactory` in `setup` method as well as `setupSpec` method with the `sessionFactory` available in the test, but that did not help unfortunately. I have thought about using an integration test, but I would really like to see if I can continue to have this unit test work as it was before. Does anyone know if I am I doing something incorrectly or if there is a workaround/solution for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Grails has a test explicitly on that : https://github.com/grails/gorm-hibernate5/blob/96cef6c569951f39b92715bb369056468b975535/grails-plugin/src/test/groovy/grails/test/mixin/hibernate/HibernateSpecSpec.groovy

You might try to add a @Entity(MyDomain) annotation on your spec class as it might trigger something so it works.

Comment: @bassmartin Thanks for your response. I don't think that @Entity(MyDomain) will work since there's no value attribute on the annotation. Also, I tried it without (MyDomain), and I saw the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was to add the annotation `@FreshRuntime` to the spec and to add a `doWithSpring` closure to the test that sets up the `sessionFactory` for me (i.e. sessionFactory(InstanceFactoryBean, sessionFactory, SessionFactory)). Also, I made sure to add both `service.sessionFactory = sessionFactory` and `service.transactionManager = transactionManager` to the `setupSpec` method. Finally, I needed to override `getDomainClasses()` to work with all of the domain objects I wanted to in the test. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Viewing source code of `HibernateSpec` could give some hint. Could be there is no `getSessionFactory()` method in Hibernate 5 grails plugin that you are using.

I am using `org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:6.0.6` with grails 3.2.5 and sessionFactory is not null for me in unit tests.

I understand that it is not always possible to upgrade, but it could give an idea what is the source of the problem.

Update:

```
service.sessionFactory = sessionFactory
```

also must be called in test setup.

Comment: Thank you. I did check the `HibernateSpec` and I see `getSessionFactory()`. I also upgraded my application to use grails 3.2.5 and to use the same version of the hibernate5 plugin. I also called `service.sessionFactory = sessionFactory` in `setup` and then in `setupSpec`. Since the service is marked Transactional, I also included `service.transactionManager = transactionManager`. I still see the same NullPointerException due to the null `sessionFactory` in the service.

Answer (score 0):

The Test Mixins have been deprecated for the new traits since 3.2.3.
https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/testing.html

> Since Grails 3.3, the Grails Testing Support Framework is used for all
> unit tests. This support provides a set of traits.

However, I still find myself using HibernateSpec as I can get multiple Domain classes from that, and the ServiceUnitTest for the service as well. The HibernateSpec has the needed sessionFactory.
E.g.

```
class MyServiceSpec extends HibernateSpec implements ServiceUnitTest<MyService>{

    List<Class> getDomainClasses() { [Tag, TagLink, TagLinkValue, TagValue, TestDomain] }
...
    def setup() {
        service.sessionFactory = sessionFactory
...
    }
// tests here with all those domain classes available and the service 
}
```

The DataTest allows for multiple domain classes, but not the service as well.
https://testing.grails.org/latest/guide/index.html#unitTestingDomainClasses

the service test allows for the service, but not multiple domain classes.
https://testing.grails.org/latest/guide/index.html#unitTestingServices

You could use both of them together, but neither one of them has the session factory (that I could see), I'm on Grails 4.0.1. I looked through Github code for the latest and still don't see it available. Plus, the DataTest doesn't a hibernate session, it uses a SimpleMap instead so you can't use hql with it, which I wanted.

My Service was using the statelessSession

```
def statelessSession = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession()
String queryString = "select DISTINCT(t.tagRef) from com.fmr.aps.taggable.TagLink t group by t.tagRef order by t.tagRef ASC"
Query query = statelessSession.createQuery(queryString)
query.setReadOnly(true);
ScrollableResults results = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
```

So I needed a unit test trait or base class with it and I spent several hours trying to make the new traits give me what I wanted. Even I began subclassing the DataTest class to try and make it give me the sessionFactory, but eventually just went with the `HibernateSpec` and it's nice to be able to run that one test class with several Domains, the Service and the sessionFactory.